# Kivy Popup misbehaviour when called from inside 'on_enter'

Tags: python, popup, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to display a Popup in case today is a date on DB.

the problem is the popup pops, but it seems to be built behind the main screen.
I am  supposing this is due to be called on "on_enter" method, but couldn't work around this.

[image]

Please, note that this "Settings" button is being rendered from the Main screen not from the popup itself.

Here is my main.py:

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from datetime import date, datetime
from calendar import weekday
from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker, MDTimePicker
from datahelper import CreateTable, InsertEstudo, DeletStudy, ReadStudy, UpdateStudy
from kivy.factory import Factory


class Gerenciador(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Main(Screen):
    # def verificar_estudos(self):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        ler_dbestudos = ReadStudy()
        resultado = ler_dbestudos.ler_estudos()
        for s in resultado:
            dia = s[2].split("-")[-1]
            mes = s[2].split("-")[-2]
            ano = s[2].split("-")[0]
            print(f"{dia}/{mes}/{ano}")
        dia_hoje = date.today().day
        mes_hoje = date.today().month
        ano_hoje = date.today().year

        if int(dia) == dia_hoje:
            print('Hoje é dia de revisão de matéria')
            tudo = self.children
            Factory.DiaDeRevisao().open()
        if int(dia) + 14 == dia_hoje:
            print('Hoje é dia de revisão de matéria')
            Factory.DiaDeRevisao().open()
        if int(mes)+1 == mes_hoje:
            print('Hoje é dia de revisão de matéria')
            Factory.DiaDeRevisao().open()


class Revisao(Screen):
    def ver_estudos(self, *args):
        read_studies = ReadStudy()
        studies = read_studies.ler_estudos()
        for s in studies:
            self.ids.scrollviewid.add_widget(TwoLineIconListItem(text=s[1], secondary_text=s[2]))

    def ver_lista(self, *args):
        for r in range(20):
            self.ids.scrollviewid.add_widget(TwoLineIconListItem(text='Azul', secondary_text="Texto Secundário"))


class AddStudy(Screen):
    def open_calendar(self):
        date_dialog = MDDatePicker(callback=self.get_date)
        if self.ids.dtinist.focused == True:
            date_dialog.open()

    def get_date(self, *args):
        '''
          :type date: <class 'datetime.date'>
          '''
        print(args[0])
        print(type(args[0]))
        self.ids.dtinist.focused = False
        self.ids.dtinist.text = str(args[0])
        self.ids.dtinist.focused = False
        return args[0]

    def open_clock(self):
        time_dialog = MDTimePicker()
        time_dialog.bind(time=self.get_time)
        if self.ids.tminist.focused == True:
            time_dialog.open()

    def get_time(self,*args):
        self.ids.tminist.focused = False
        self.ids.tminist.text = str(args[1])
        self.ids.tminist.focused = False
        return args[1]

    def selected(self, path, selection):
        tipo = selection[0].split(".")[-1]
        print(tipo)
        if tipo == 'mp3':
            toast('Arquivo MP3 selecionado')
            with open(selection[0], 'rb') as f:
                barq = f.read()
                insert = InsertEstudo()
                insert.criar_novo_estudo()

    def confirm_new(self):
        materia = self.ids.materia_estudo.text
        data_estudo = self.ids.dtinist.text
        hora_estudo = self.ids.tminist.text
        insert_new_study = InsertEstudo()

        if insert_new_study.criar_novo_estudo(materia, data_estudo, hora_estudo):
            toast('Estudo adicionado com sucesso')
        else:
            toast('Algo deu muito errado. O estudo não foi adicionado. Tente novamente mais tarde')


class SettingsScreen(Screen):

    def select_path(self, path):
        print(path)
        '''It will be called when you click on the file name
        or the catalog selection button.

        :type path: str;
        :param path: path to the selected directory or file;
        '''

        self.exit_manager()
        toast(path)

    def open_file_manager(self):
        self.file_manager.show('/')  # output manager to the screen
        self.manager_open = True

    def exit_manager(self):
        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager.close()


class SelectAlarm(Screen):
    def selected(self, path, selection):
        tipo = selection[0].split(".")[-1]
        print(tipo)
        if tipo == 'mp3':
            toast('Arquivo MP3 selecionado')
            with open(selection[0], 'rb') as f:
                barq = f.read()
                insert = InsertEstudo()
                insert.criar_novo_estudo()
        else:
            toast('Por favor, seleecione um arquivo mp3')


class BoraEstudarApp(MDApp):

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def build(self):
        data_hoje = f"{date.today().year}-{date.today().month}-{date.today().day}"
        sm = Gerenciador()
        sm.add_widget(Main(name='Principal'))
        sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='Preferencias'))
        sm.add_widget(AddStudy(name='NovaMateria'))
        sm.add_widget(Revisao(name='Revisoes'))
        sm.add_widget(SelectAlarm(name='SelecionarAlarme'))

        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    boraestudar = BoraEstudarApp()
    boraestudar.run()
```

and here is my kv file:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
<ScreenManager>:


<DiaDeRevisao@Popup>:
    title: 'Atenção dia de revisão'
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint:0.7,0.7
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:(1,1,1,1)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
            MDLabel:
                text:'Hoje é dia de revisão'
            Button:
                text: 'OK'
                on_press: root.dismiss()

<FileChooserPop@Popup>:
    title:'Escolha o arquivo de audio MP3'
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:(0,0,0,0.35)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        orientation: 'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: sp(52)

            Button:
                text: 'Icon View'
                on_press: fc.view_mode = 'icon'
            Button:
                text: 'List View'
                on_press: fc.view_mode = 'list'

        FileChooser:
            id: fc
            FileChooserIconLayout
            FileChooserListLayout

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            MDTextButton:
                size_hint_x:0.4
                text: 'Voltar'
                on_press: root.dismiss()

            MDIconButton:
                halign:'center'
                icon:'content-save'
                on_press:root.selected(fc.path, fc.selection)
                on_release: root.manager.current = 'Principal'

<Main>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        spacing:'50dp'
        padding:'70dp'
        BoxLayout:
            MDTextButton:
                text: 'Revisões'
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'Revisoes'
#                on_release:Factory.FileChooserPop().open()
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Settings'
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'Preferencias'
        BoxLayout:
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "plus"
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'NovaMateria'


<AddStudy>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        spacing:'100sp'
        padding: '100dp'
        MDTextField:
            id:materia_estudo
            hint_text: 'Matéria'

        MDTextField:
            id: dtinist
            text: ''
            hint_text: 'data do Estudo'
            on_focus: root.open_calendar()

        MDTextField:
            id:tminist
            text:''
            hint_text: 'Hora do Estudo'
            on_focus: root.open_clock()

        BoxLayout:
            MDTextButton:
                text:'Voltar'
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'Principal'
            MDTextButton:
                text: 'Salvar'
                on_press: root.confirm_new()
<SettingsScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        MDTextButton:
            text: 'Selecionar Alarme'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'SelecionarAlarme'


<SelectAlarm>:
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:(0,0,0,0.35)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        orientation: 'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: sp(52)

            Button:
                text: 'Icon View'
                on_press: fc.view_mode = 'icon'
            Button:
                text: 'List View'
                on_press: fc.view_mode = 'list'

        FileChooser:
            id: fc
            FileChooserIconLayout
            FileChooserListLayout

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            MDTextButton:
                size_hint_x:0.4
                text: 'Voltar'
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'Principal'

            MDIconButton:
                halign:'center'
                icon:'content-save'
                on_press:root.selected(fc.path, fc.selection)
                on_release: root.manager.current = 'Principal'

<Revisao>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            ScrollView:
                do_scroll_y: True
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '500dp'
                MDList:
                    id:scrollviewid
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 0.15
            MDTextButton:
                size_hint_x: None
                text:"Voltar"
                on_release: root.manager.current = 'Principal'
            MDTextButton:
                text:"Ver Lista"
                on_release: root.ver_estudos()
```

This is odd and I couldn't figure this out.

I appreciate any help. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `on_enter()` event is triggered too early, so it the `Popup` gets drawn before the `Main` `Screen`. You can fix that by adding a very short delay before displaying the `Popup`. I changing the:

```
Factory.DiaDeRevisao().open()
```

to:

```
Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: Factory.DiaDeRevisao().open())
```

will provide that delay and allow the `Popup` to display on top of the `Screen`.

Comment: Superb! Absolutely right. I Knew there was something with the time, but completely forgotten about the Clock thing... Thanks, Mate!